# Jquery на javascript.

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть код (http://jsfiddle.net/ почему-то не работает).

html

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header"><h1>Ты что делаешь ?!</h1></div>
    <div id="content"><h1>Dont click!</h1></div>
    <div id="footer"><h1>Не нажимать !)</h1></div>
</div>
    <script>
myfun();
document.write ("<hr/>")

</script>

<div id="input_id"><input id="inputt" type="button" value="Dont click!" onclick="myfun2();"></div>

</body>
```

JS

```
> function myfun() {
document.write ("<p>Hello</p>");
document.write ("<p>User</p>");
document.write ("<p>You Good Boy :D</p>");
$('h1').hide(0);
}

function myfun2 () {
$('h1').show(1000);
$('h1').hide(3000);
}
```

Как мне сделать то же самое только на Javascript без JQuery?

Comment: Интересует именно myfun2

Comment: Через GetElementID и изменять стили?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не работает на jsfiddle, так как

1. Он не умеет работать с встроенными в тег функциями обработки, если они отделены в js секцию.
2. Там запрещено использовать document.write()
3. [Вот так](http://jsfiddle.net/0c24pvyx/) работает

---

Если хотите сделать это без jquery, то придется вручную увеличивать и уменьшать высоту элемента и прозрачность(если надо) с помощью setInterval, а так же позаботиться о кроссбраузерности.

Comment: @Alex Krass, проблема была не с тем, что на фиддле не работало, а с тем что jsfiddle вообще не работал :)